# Tramp, transfer configuration file

Tags: tramp, ssh

To establish an ssh connection, I use the configuration file.`;ssh remoteHost -F /home/alamd/ПакетыДоступа/root_91_211_249_142/config`. Is it possible to transfer ssh connection settings from such a file to tramp? I found that it is possible to pass options through

> 'tramp-ssh-controlmaster-options'

, but it seems there is no option to transfer the configuration file. Thanks.

Comment: Access data for the host is taken from the database. No connection traces should remain in the file system. When using the configuration file, that flexibility is achieved when connecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to use this config file in Tramp instead of `~/.ssh/config`, you need to tell Tramp so in `tramp-methods`. Something like

```
(progn
  (require 'tramp-sh)
  (let ((args (assoc 'tramp-login-args (assoc "ssh" tramp-methods))))
    (setcar
      (cdr args)
      (append
        '(("-F" "/home/alamd/ПакетыДоступа/root_91_211_249_142/config"))
        (cadr args)))))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. It was not possible to use SSH certificates to open files on remote hosts in emacs. Glad your cooperation.